# StructureMap resolve all instances for generic type at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, structuremap

For the following container registration:

```
c.For(typeof(IHandler<bool>)).Use(typeof(BoolHandler));
c.For(typeof(IHandler<int>)).Use(typeof(IntHandler));
```

I'm trying to get a list of types at run time like so:

```
var test = Container.Current.Get(typeof(IHandler<>)); // doesn't work
var test = Container.Current.GetAllInstances<IHandler<object>>(); // doesn't work
```

I get count of 0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `Get(typeof(IHandler<>))` because it is impossible to create an instance of an open-generic type; this is impossible in the CLR.

Resolving a collection of `IHandler<object>` would only result any elements either when you have explicitly registered an `IHandler<object>` -or- when the `IHandler<T>` is defined as covariant, i.e. using the `out` keyword as `IHandler<out T>`. Without having `in` or `out` keywords on your interface, your interface is not variant and it is impossible to cast a closed version of an interface to another closed version of that same interface.

Only when the abstraction is defined as `IHandler<out T>` is is possible to assign an `IHandler<string>` to an `IHandler<object>` because `T` will be an output argument and `string` can be casted to `object`.

It is unlikely that this is useful to you, since handlers typically have an input argument. However, when the abstraction is defined as `IHandler<in T>` (which makes much more sense) this means that you can only assign an `IHandler<object>` from an `IHandler<string>`, because you can pass in a string argument into an `IHandler<object>` but not the other way around.

To make this more concrete, the following will compile:

```
interface IHandler<in T> { }

var handlers = new IHandler<string>[]
{
    new Handler<string>(),
    new Handler<object>(),
};
```

But the following won't:

```
interface IHandler<in T> { }

var handlers = new IHandler<object>[]
{
    new Handler<string>(),
    new Handler<object>(),
};
```

Likewise, the following will compile:

```
interface IHandler<out T> { }

var handlers = new IHandler<object>[]
{
    new Handler<string>(),
    new Handler<object>(),
};
```

But the following won't:

```
interface IHandler<out T> { }

var handlers = new IHandler<string>[]
{
    new Handler<string>(),
    new Handler<object>(),
};
```

Since this holds for C# and the CLR in general, there is no way for StructureMap (or any container) to work around this. And that's why you won't got any results.

Comment: Perfect explanation. Makes sense. Thanks so much!